# How to adapt a per-line background to parshape?

Tags: luatex, rules

I've been adding rules behind each line of text in LuaTeX by filling `\localleftbox` with a box whose width is set to 0 but whose contents are rules of length `\textwidth`.  So long as I have standard shaped paragraphs, this works fine.  However, I've now come across a situation where I'd like to do the same thing with a paragraph whose shape has been manipulated with `\parshape`.

In the below MWE, the rules, since they are created in the beginning of the document at a fixed width, don't adapt to the paragraph shape.  Is there a way to make them responsive to the paragraph shape?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newdimen\lefttest
\lefttest=1.5in
\newdimen\righttest
\righttest=1in

\localleftbox{\hbox to 0pt{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\parshape=5
0in \dimexpr\textwidth-\righttest\relax
\lefttest \dimexpr\textwidth-\lefttest-\righttest\relax
\lefttest \dimexpr\textwidth-\lefttest-\righttest\relax
\lefttest \dimexpr\textwidth-\lefttest\relax
0in \textwidth
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not consider an existing package like [`ulem`](//ctan.org/pkg/ulem)? See [this example code](https://pastebin.com/raw/MA75bWU4).

Comment: `left` and `\right` are brave names to choose for your length registers since they over-write tex primitives

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't realize that.  I'll edit.

Comment: @Werner I've used a single simple rule for the purposes of the MWE.  The actual use case has multiple rules with some rather specific spacing requirements (above, below, and between).

Comment: you would I think be better to not use the localparbox and instead use the post linebrealk filter to iterate over the lines and add your rules

Comment: @MarcelKrüger it compiled originally but I told the OP not to use `\left` as a dimen. (I'll finish off the edit)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Oops.  Sorry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have to admit that while I've reused code that makes use of `post_linebreak_filter`, I've never really understood it and wouldn't have the first clue as to how to write one from scratch.  Can you point to a resource that walks one through the process so that I could learn?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1090+post_linebreak_filter

Answer (score 1):

As other people told you in the comments, `\localleftbox` isn't a good solution for this since it only accepts a fixed box which will not change, therefore you would need to set a new `\localleftbox` whenever the line length changes, which in turn would need you to know how the lines will be broken. At that point, you could also just add the background manually.

Especially if your background consists of "rules" (where rules should be interpreted in the LuaTeX sense, therefore e.g. images are "rules" too), you can use pre-existing packages for this by looking into packages intended for underlining as Werner suggested. I am obviously biased, but I would recommend my `lua-ul` package here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\newdimen\lefttest
\lefttest=1.5in
\newdimen\righttest
\righttest=1in

% You can easily add more \newunderlinetype lines as long as you replace
% \paragraphlines with a unique name for each.
\newunderlinetype\paragraphlines[]{\leaders\vrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt}
\newunderlinetype\topparagraphlines[]{\leaders\vrule height 10pt depth -9.6pt}

\begin{document}

% Now activate the lines. This has to come after \begin{document}. These respect TeX groups if you only want to apply them to some parts. 
\paragraphlines
\topparagraphlines

\noindent
\parshape=5
0in \dimexpr\textwidth-\righttest\relax
\lefttest \dimexpr\textwidth-\lefttest-\righttest\relax
\lefttest \dimexpr\textwidth-\lefttest-\righttest\relax
\lefttest \dimexpr\textwidth-\lefttest\relax
0in \textwidth
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks more promising than expected, but will require a more substantial rewrite of a whole bunch of related code to integrate it into my package.  It's going to take a while before I have the time to really sit down and do that.